# Splitting a document from a tm Corpus into multiple documents

Tags: regex, r, split, tm, text-analysis

A bit of a bizarre question, is there a way to split corpus documents that have been imported using the Corpus function in tm into multiple documents that can then be reread in my Corpus as separate documents? For example if I used
`inspect(documents[1])` and had something like

```
`<<VCorpus (documents: 1, metadata (corpus/indexed): 0/0)>>`

`[[1]]`

`<<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>`

The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog

I think cats are really cool

I want to split after this line!!!

Hi mom

Purple is my favorite color

I want to split after this line!!!

Words

And stuff
```

and I want to split the document after the phrase "I want to split after this line!!!" appears, twice in this case, is that possible?

The end result would look like this after using `inspect(documents)`

`<<VCorpus (documents: 1, metadata (corpus/indexed): 0/0)>>`

> `[[1]]`
>
> `<<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>`
>
> The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
>
> I think cats are really cool
>
> I want to split after this line!!!
>
> `[[2]]`
>
> `<<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>`
>
> Hi mom
>
> Purple is my favorite color
>
> I want to split after this line!!!
>
> `[[3]]`
>
> `<<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>`
>
> Words
>
> And stuff

Comment: Probably you can manipulate the internals, but why? What purpose are you trying to serve? Do you e.g. want to generate separate term-frequency or tfidf matrices for subsections?

Comment: I have code to extract data from many identically formatted documents, but it turns out the "real" data (as opposed to the test data I was allowed to work with off of the office computer) has the PDFs merged instead of split. I figured it would be easier to deal with it in R than to manually split the hundreds of documents from each other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `strsplit` to split your document , then recreate the corpus again :

```
Corpus(VectorSource(
          strsplit(as.character(documents[[1]]),  ## coerce to character
          "I want to split after this line!!!",   
          fixed=TRUE)[[1]]))       ## use fixed=T since you  have special
                                   ## characters in your separator
```

To test this , we should first create a reproducible example :

```
documents <- Corpus(VectorSource(paste(readLines(textConnection("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
I think cats are really cool
I want to split after this line!!!
Hi mom
Purple is my favorite color
I want to split after this line!!!
Words
And stuff")),collapse='\n')))
```

Then applying previous solution:

```
split.docs <- Corpus(VectorSource(
  strsplit(as.character(documents[[1]]),  ## coerce to character
           "I want to split after this line!!!",   
           fixed=TRUE)[[1]]))
```

Now inspect the solution :

```
inspect(split.docs)
<<VCorpus (documents: 3, metadata (corpus/indexed): 0/0)>>

[[1]]
<<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>
The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
I think cats are really cool


[[2]]
<<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>

Hi mom
Purple is my favorite color


[[3]]
<<PlainTextDocument (metadata: 7)>>

Words
And stuff
```

looks that `strsplit` remove the separator :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an even easier way, using the `quanteda` package:

```
require(quanteda)
segment(mytext, what = "other", delimiter = "I want to split after this line!!!")
```

This produces a list of length=1 (since it is designed to with multiple documents, if you wish) but you can always `unlist()` it if you just want a vector.

```
[[1]]
[1] "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog\n\nI think cats are really cool\n\n"
[2] "\n    \nHi mom\n\nPurple is my favorite color\n\n"                               
[3] "\n    \nWords\n\nAnd stuff"
```

This can be read back into a `quanteda` corpus using `corpus(mytextSegmented)` or a `tm` corpus for subsequent processing.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this method on my document `docs[1]`, which is a VCorpus.  I used `segment(docs[1], what = "other", delimiter = "I want to split after this line!!!")` and got the error: no applicable method for 'segment' applied to an object of class "c('VCorpus', 'Corpus')". Any tips?

Comment: Yes, your options are: a) extract the texts from the VCorpus so that your `mytext` as in my example is a character object - and I honestly do not know how to do this in `tm`, which is one of the reasons we developed `quanteda`; b) don't create a VCorpus at all, just use `segment()` directly on your vectorsource character object; or c) use `segment()` on a `quanteda` corpus which you can create from your VCorpus object using `quanteda::corpus(myVCorpus)`.  Substituting my example object names for your actual ones of course.